# when i enter mon it needs to display 1 & for yr 12

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

```
select &enter,
       case 
           when enter=mon then '1'
           when enter=yr then '12'
           else '0'
       end as status
from dual
```

Comment: What is the mon, enter and yr? are these your inputs? And please explain what you want.

Comment: Mon is month & yr is year , im right?So try `CASE` clause

Comment: when i enter mon it should display as 1 in output when i enter yr it should display as 12.     required o/p   enter  status
                                                 month   1

Answer (score 1):

Based on the original code:

```
select '&enter',
       case 
           when '&enter'='mon' then '1'
           when '&enter'='yr' then '12'
           else '0'
       end as status
from dual
```

Suggested code:

```
select '&enter',
       case '&enter'
           when 'mon' then 1
           when 'yr'  then 12
           else 0
       end as status
from dual
```